# enum declared within master page can't access from the content page

Tags: c#, enums, master-pages, content-pages

Hi I have declared an enum within the master page as

```
public enum AlertType
        {
            success = 1,
            danger,
            warning,
            info,
            primary,
            secondary,
            light,
            dark
        }
```

But when I tried to access one element of this enum inside my content page using `string Name = this.Master.AlertType.danger.ToString();` it gives an error 'cannot reference a type through an expression'. What to do with this error? how can I access those values inside the enum here in my content page?

Comment: Can you post the full code where you accessing the enum

Comment: I tried to access it within the ` !ispostback ` section.

Comment: `this.Master.AlertType` is a reference to an *instance* value. The enum *type* `AltertType` is not part of the instance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error message says. You're using a local property `this.Master.AlertType` to access an enum. This property has a value of its own (maybe `success`) so it makes no sense to add `.danger` to it.

Try

```
string Name = AlertType.danger.ToString();
```

Comment: But I can't access the AlertType directly in the content page??

Comment: Then you probably need to reference the class that owns it. We don't know what that is, because we've not seen the rest of your code. It'll be something like `masterPage.AlertType.danger.ToString()`

Comment: Yes I can access it with Master page name. But I am asking about why we can't use this.Master instead?

Comment: I already set master type VirtualPath and everything and I can access all other variables declared public within master page using this.Master

Comment: because this.Master is an object with properties. It represents a single thing with properties that have values. The class that defines it (and contains the enum) are the blueprint from which it is built. The compiler needs to know whether your referring to the class or the object. I suppose it could work it out, but it's not that clever.